# How to automate API get data request? when using web sockets

Tags: node.js, ajax, api, sockets, get

As far as I know Web Sockets allows bi-directional communication. and web sockets (for example: Socket.io) connections are always open. so, whenever new data has arrived data should be automatically pushed to the view via socket.

but in below code I am using **set_interval** to make a http.get call. and set_interval is called once every 1 second.

now, doing these does not give a real-time feel that is, the new data is pulled once every 1 second. which is statically defined.

in-short, **I want to automate what set_interval does in below code**. I don't want a static fetch interval value. This is because **at-times stock price could change within 100ms and at times it would change once in few seconds**.

Now, if I set interval to 1 sec, that is make a call every 1 second. the real feel of high fluctuation in market move would not be seen.

I am not sure how usually developers fetch data in IOT applications. for example car is monitored in real-time and let's say speed of the car is fetched in real time and graphed on a web or mobile application.

**How do I achieve something similar like that in Stock Ticker?** I want to simply plugin the application to an API and when new data arrives instantly push it to all the viewers (subscribers) in real-time.

## Code below

```
////
// CONFIGURATION SETTINGS
////
var FETCH_INTERVAL = 1000;
var PRETTY_PRINT_JSON = true;

////
// START
////
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var io = require('socket.io');
var cors = require('cors');

function getQuote(socket, ticker) {
    https.get({
        port: 443,
        method: 'GET',
        hostname: 'www.google.com',
        path: '/finance/info?client=ig&q=' + ticker,
        timeout: 1000
    }, function(response) {
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        var data = '';

        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function() {
            if(data.length > 0) {
                var dataObj;

                try {
                    dataObj = JSON.parse(data.substring(3));
                } catch(e) {
                    return false;
                }

                socket.emit(ticker, dataObj[0].l_cur);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I am making a call to method getQuote depending on FETCH_INTERVAL set above

```
function trackTicker(socket, ticker) {
    // run the first time immediately
    getQuote(socket, ticker);

    // every N seconds
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        getQuote(socket, ticker);
    }, FETCH_INTERVAL);

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
    });
}

var app = express();
app.use(cors());
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = io.listen(server);
io.set('origins', '*:*');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('ticker', function(ticker) {
        trackTicker(socket, ticker);
    });
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000);
```

## Edits - Update

Okay, so I would need real-time feed. (this bit is sorted)

As far as I know, Real-time feeds are quite expensive and buying 10,000+ end points for each online client is quite expensive.

1) How do I make use of real-time feed to serve 1000s of end users? Can I use web sockets, Redis, publish/subscribe, broadcasting or some technology that copies real-time feed to tonnes of users? I want a efficient solution because I want to keep the expense of real-time data feed as low as possible.

How do I tackle that issue?

2) Yes, I understand polling needs to be done on server side and not on a client-side (to avoid doing polling for each client). but then what tech do I need to use? websockets, redis, pub/sub etc..

I have API URL and a token to access the API.

3) I am not just in need to fetch the data and push it to end users. But I would need to do some computation on the fetched data, will need to pull data from Redis or database as well and do calculations on it then push it to the view.

for example:

```
1) data I get in real-time market feed {"a":10, "b":20}
2) get data from DB or Redis  {"x":2, "y":4} 
3) do computation : z = a * x + b * y
4) finally push value of z in the view.
```

How do I do all these in real-time at the same-time push it to multiple clients?
**Can you share a roadmap with me?** I got the first piece of the puzzle getting real-time datafeed.

Comment: To get more realtime (as opposed to polling on the server), you need some sort of realtime feed from your stock price source so it tells you when a given stock price you are monitoring changes.  You then have your server keep track of which client is watching which stocks and you send the update for a given stock price immediately to any client that is watching that stock.  Polling once on the server is more efficient than polling in every client, but its still polling and subject to the non-real-time aspects of polling.  The only way to get rid of that is to get a real-time feed from source.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh okay, I see what you mean. so only if the feed is in real-time I can avoid doing checks every set_interval. can we chat for few minutes? I have few more questions regarding the same subject.

Comment: Please put your questions into your question (and then  add a comment to point to the edits), not offline where others can't see them.

Comment: Plus, if 100 clients are each watching a given stock, you don't want to be polling 100 times for that stock price.  You want to be polling once for it and then forwarding that one quote to all 100 clients.  So, you have to rethink that way of what you're doing also.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated my question and added 3 questions to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) How do I make use of real-time feed to serve 1000s of end users? Can I use web sockets, Redis, publish/subscribe, broadcasting or some technology that copies real-time feed to tonnes of users? I want a efficient solution because I want to keep the expense of real-time data feed as low as possible.
>
> How do I tackle that issue?

To "push" data to browser clients, you would want to use a webSocket or socket.io (built on top of webSockets).  Then, anytime your server knows there's an update, it can immediately send that update to any currently connected client that is interested in that info.  The basic idea is that the client connects to your server as soon as the web page is loaded and keeps that connection open for as long as the web page(s) are open.

> 2) Yes, I understand polling needs to be done on server side and not on a client-side (to avoid doing polling for each client). but then what tech do I need to use? websockets, redis, pub/sub etc..

It isn't clear to me what exactly you're asking about here.  You will get updated prices using whatever the most efficient technology is that is offered by your provider.  If all they provide is http calls, then you have to poll regularly using http requests.  If they provide a webSocket interface to get updates, then that would be preferable.

There are lots of choices for how to keep track of which clients are interested in which pieces of information and how to distribute the updates.  For a single server, you could easily build your own with just a Map of stock prices where the stock symbol is the key and an array of client identifiers is the value in the Map.  Then, any time you get an update for a given stock, you just fetch the list of client IDs that are interested in that stock and send the update to them (over their webSocket/socket.io connection).

This is also a natural pub/sub type of application so anyone of the backends that support pub/sub would work just fine too.  You could even use an EventEmitter where you `.emit(stock, price)` and each separate connection adds a listener for the stock symbols they are interested in.

For multiple servers at scale, you'd probably want to use some external process that manages the pub/sub process.  Redis is a candidate for that.

> 3) I am not just in need to fetch the data and push it to end users. But I would need to do some computation on the fetched data, will need to pull data from Redis or database as well and do calculations on it then push it to the view.

I don't really see what question there is here.  Pick your favorite database to store the info you need to fetch so you can get it upon demand.

> How do I do all these in real-time at the same-time push it to multiple clients? Can you share a roadmap with me? I got the first piece of the puzzle getting real-time datafeed.

1. Real-time data feed.
2. Database to store your meta data used for calculations.
3. Some pub/sub system, either home built or from a pre-built package.

Then, follow this sequence of events.

1. Client signs in, connects a webSocket or socket.io connection.
2. Server accepts client connection and assigns a clientID and keeps track of the connection in some sort of Map between clientID and webSocket/socket.io connection.  FYI, socket.io does this automatically for you.
3. Client tells server which items it wants to monitor (probably message sent over webSocket/socket.io connection.
4. Server registers that interest in pub/sub system (essentially subscribing the client to each item it wants to monitor.
5. Other clients do the same thing.
6. Each time client requests data on a specific item, the server makes sure that it is getting updates for that item (however the server gets its updates).
7. Server gets new info for some item that one or more clients is interested in.
8. New data is sent to pub/sub system and pub/sub system broadcasts that information to those clients that were interested in info on that particular item.  The details of how that works depend upon what pub/sub system you choose and how it notifies subscribers of a change, but eventually a message is sent over webSocket/socket.io for the item that has changed.
9. When a client disconnects, their pub/sub subscriptions are "unsubscribed".

Comment: okay I got my answer for second question. That is, it's best to use ws (websocket non-secure) or wss (websocket secure protocol) over http for real-time data because websockets protocol is full-duplex communication channel and it  enables interaction between a browser and a web server with lower overheads, facilitating real-time data transfer from and to the server

Comment: in Q3, the reason I asked about database is because: if I use mongoDB let's say as a DB. then what I think is that, isn't it bad to open and close mongodb connection every second to fetch data? that's why I thought redis in-memory caching would be better and I can cache new values from database every once in a while rather than every second, isnt it? I thought database are heavy operations and time-consuming. I dont know what is the best way to store some data which is updated by admin and is also used for calculations very frequently

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia - What database to select depends upon your specific requirements which is a non-trivial task to research and draw a proper conclusion for.  If you have no need for regular data persistence to disk and the data set easily fits in memory, then redis is a common choice.  For mongoDB, there's no need to open and close the connection all the time.  You can open one connection and keep it open to then make multiple queries over that one connection.  Database operations can be heavy or light depending upon the operation, the type of database and how optimized your query is.

Comment: last question. If I am not wrong, I see 2 different types of pub/sub system here. One pub/sub system (ex: redis pub/sub) does registration of what clients (X) are interested in what products (Y) in order to serve right information. And another sort of pub/sub I see is the one socket.io uses. for example: if 10 users visit http://localhost:8000/live page then all 10 users are automatically subscribed to that page if any user leaves that page they are unsubscribed. ex: on server :var nsp = io.of('/ch1'); nsp.emit('live', array);  on client side:socket.on('live', function(msg) {//data}

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia - In your second example, you are just using the URL of the page to automatically specify what resource a user is interested in watching (fixed set of resources per page).  The underlying pub/sub is really no different.  Your first example is infinitely more flexible.